# Button to become input

Tags: html, button, dynamic, input

Im trying to creat a button to add a username typed by the user but the functionality that im looking for is to have the button become the text input , I have created the following:

```
<button type="button" class="btn widget uib_w_16 btncolor_green noborder_btn btn-default" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/button" data-ver="0" id="addfriend_btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user button-icon-top" data-position="top"></i>
                       </button>
```

But I have no idea on how to make it or convert it into an input so I can add the desired username. please can anyone give me a lead or an idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: Why have it become the input? Why not just show a hidden input after clicking it?

Comment: You'd need javascript. For this sort of thing, jQuery would make life easier, and then it's just some DOM operations. capture the click, delete the button node, replace with an `<input>` node.

Comment: @MarcB is right, no way to archive this without some JavaScript.

Comment: can anyone provide a simple example? or anything.